# SQlite From clause SELECT statement

Tags: android, sqlite

My requirement is list of table in the list , when looping the list need to get the android table name from mapping table & call that table name:

see my query :

```
 SELECT * FROM SELECT ToTable  FROM RDSynchronisationControlHeader 
 WHERE FromTable ='RD.TransactionControl'
```

When I run this query from query browser, This is not working?
Can't we use select statement in the from clause?

```
  private boolean isTableRecords(String tablename){
    DBAdapter dbAdapter = DBAdapter.getDBAdapterInstance(this);
    boolean recordStatus = false;
      try {
          dbAdapter.createDataBase();
     } catch (IOException e) {
          Log.i("*** select ",e.getMessage());
     }
     dbAdapter.openDataBase();
     String query = "SELECT * FROM SELECT ToTable FROM RDSynchronisationControlHeader WHERE FromTable ='?';";

     String[]d = new String[]{tablename};
     ArrayList stringList = dbAdapter.selectRecordsFromDBList(query, d);


     dbAdapter.close();

     ArrayList<Object> wmRouteList = new ArrayList<Object>();
     recordStatus =  stringList.size() >0 ? true : false;
    return recordStatus;
}
```

Please help me..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Clear question brings quicker answer.So u need a query that will select from a table that name is in the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a big SQLite guy, but in any environment I've worked in, when you use a sub-select, you'll want the subquery to be in parentheses, like:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT ToTable
        FROM RDSynchronisationControlHeader 
        WHERE FromTable ='RD.TransactionControl'
    )
```

Comment: I have tried like this also. `SELECT ToTable
        FROM RDSynchronisationControlHeader 
        WHERE FromTable ='RD.TransactionControl'` this return table name, samething when i called like this `SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT ToTable
        FROM RDSynchronisationControlHeader 
        WHERE FromTable ='RD.TransactionControl'
    )` this one also return table name, that means return subquery result..

Comment: I get it - I didn't understand your question at first. I think your subquery returns you a table name, and you want to do a `SELECT *` from that table. No matter how you accomplish this, it will be two queries - can't do it in just one. You'll have to run your first query to get the table name, then build your SQL statement to run the real query. Even in an environment with stored procs, you could dynamically build the statement in a proc, but it would still fire two queries. But since you're in SQLite, it's moot anyway.

Comment: your assumption is correct .subquery returns table name, and i need  to do a SELECT * from that table.With one query I couldn't do it...

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible as a query in the form of

```
$stored_value = SELECT ToTable FROM RDSynchronisationControlHeader WHERE FromTable = 'RD.TransactionControl';

$final_value = SELECT * FROM quote($stored_value);
```

That may or may not work as is, SQL is not my forte. However, the quote function is capable of turning text into a Table identifier, which is what I believe you need.

Comment: I want to execute in one query , thats why i tried like  that

Comment: Also, the `$stored_value`, `$final_value` variables are PHP style. Make sure you change that. I'm working on a big PHP, Actionscript, SQL project, and the PHP style was subconscious.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite's syntax diagrams (www.sqlite.org) for the SELECT statement contain a confusion between a table's contents and a table's name.

Suppose there's a table called xxxx in your database:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT tbl_name  FROM sqlite_master WHERE tbl_name = 'xxxx' AND Type='table');
```

returns a totally different result than

```
SELECT * FROM 'xxxx'
```

In the first statement the table-or-subquery is something treated as a table's contents, in the second statement the table-or-subquery is a table's name.

So you have to do something like Josh's answer.  Run SQLite twice, using the result of the first invocation to construct the second SQL statement.